# SQL Constraint-Insert Fails

Tags: sql-server

I have two table table1 and table2. I have a record in table1. I want to insert record into table2. but it comes up with the following Exception.

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Table2_<Column3>". The conflict occurred in database "<databaseName>", table "table1", column 'Id'.
```

The constraint on the table2 is like this.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__table2__name__0B91BA14]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [column4]
```

Comment: show table schema and the data you are trying to insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is telling you which constraint is causing the issue. It's against Column3 (at least that's what the name suggests) and is a foreign key constraint against table1.

You're not showing any sample SQL but it would appear you're trying to insert data in to table2 where the foreign key value specified for Column3 does not exist in table1.

Answer (score 2):

The error shows that you also have a foreign key constraint and you are trying to insert a row into a child table that doesn't have corresponding record in master

Answer (score 0):

Your Comment helped me.

I have used this Query to insert data into the new database from the old databse.

```
INSERT INTO Database.[dbo].[Table2] ([colmn1]
      ,[colmn2]
      ,[colmn3]
      ,[columns4]
      )
SELECT [colmn1]
      ,[colmn2]
      ,[colmn3]
      ,[columns4]
  FROM [OtherDatabase].[dbo].[Table2]
```

But there is a constarint on colum3 which is foreign key on Table1.

I have changed the colmn3 of table1 to same Guid as otherDatabase Guid and it works.

Thanks All